# How to change/define Text position

Tags: swiftui

If I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

I have this result:

[image]

How can I position precisely from code "Hello World" in the upper part of the view, as shown in the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your `Text` to the top of the screen you need to wrap it in a `VStack` and place a `Spacer` below to push the text to the top of the screen:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World!")
            // all the modifiers
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

`Text` takes only the amount of spaces it needs, while `Spacer` will occupy any space given to it.